# Logging reading of a list item

Tags: logging

We would like to know whenever a person has read a list item.

Is there an event we can hook on to, or another way to log reading of an item.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SharePoint does have Item-Level Auditing (at least it did in 2007, I'm assuming it's also available in 2010). This can track "views" of items. Maybe it'll help.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397403(office.12).aspx#MOSS2007ItemLevelAudit_ItemLevelAuditing